# How can I pull in more WordPress posts from my angular app, using the WordPress REST api

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, wordpress

I am trying to build a page of WordPress posts, showing 4 initially and then lazy load these in onclick of a "Load More" button. This list will be filterable via angular.

I am using the json rest api plugin for WordPress, and my angular app is currently:

```
var myapp = angular.module( 'myapp', [] );

// Set the configuration
myapp.run( ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    // Variables defined by wp_localize_script
    $rootScope.api = aeJS.api;

}]);

// Add a controller
myapp.controller( 'mycontroller', ['$scope', '$http', function( $scope, $http ) {

    // Load posts from the WordPress API
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $scope.api,
        params: {
            'filter[posts_per_page]' : 4
        },
    }).
    success( function( data, status, headers, config ) {
        $scope.posts = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});

    $scope.loadmore = function(){
        $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(data);
    }



}]);
```

I am just a bit clueless with how to get the next 4 posts each time the load more button is clicked. I have setup a loadmore function which I am calling on click of the button:

```
<button ng-click="loadmore()">Load more articles</button>
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: could you look at `ng-infinite-scroll` https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/ which will load other records lazily

Comment: Thanks for the link, but not really, needs to be on click.

Comment: you need to implement server side paging first then pass `pageNumber` & `query` from the clientside as query param through URL

Comment: Ok, thanks for this, however I don't know how to implement the server side paging etc. Apologies, I am quite new to angular and this rest malarkey. Gonna have a Google but if you could provide some more information I'd be really grateful.

Comment: server side paging is normal process, get into the picture when we have large amount of data and wanted to show data in parts..could you tell me which technology you are using right now?

Comment: This is a WordPress website with the rest api plugin installed: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/.

Comment: Look at mine answer..will give you an good idea of your problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done - with the help from a friend, this solution is working nicely:

```
var myapp = angular.module( 'myapp', [] );

// Set the configuration
myapp.run( ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    // Variables defined by wp_localize_script
    $rootScope.api = aeJS.api;

}]);

myapp.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.init = function() {
        $http({ // Load posts from the WordPress API
            method: 'GET',
            url: $scope.api,
            params: {
                'filter[posts_per_page]' : 4
            },
        }).
        success( function( data, status, headers, config ) {
            $scope.posts = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
    };
    var page = 2;
    $scope.getData = function() {
        $http({ // Load posts from the WordPress API
            method: 'GET',
            url: $scope.api,
            params: {
                'filter[posts_per_page]': 4,
                'page': page
            },
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(data);
            page++;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
    };

    $scope.loadmore = function() {
        $scope.getData();
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use paging which has already implemented in [**wordpress API.**](http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts_response)

You need to increment your posts_per_page on each ajax call.

**Controller**

```
myapp.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var count = 0;
     $scope.posts = []; //setted as blank
    $scope.getData = function() {
        // Load posts from the WordPress API
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $scope.api,
            params: {
                'filter[posts_per_page]': 4,
                'filter[page]': ++count
            },
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
    };

    $scope.loadmore = function() {
        $scope.getData();
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Hi... this produces an error for me, count is not defined. Also, if I get this to work, what would I add to the loadmore() function to increment the count and append the extra posts?

Comment: @zeKoko if you look at my comment..you need to declared `var count=1` out side you `$http` function that will take care of this..

Comment: Thank you! Ok, I have added this, but I still don't understand how the extra posts get added to the page on click of the load more button.

Comment: thanks, I have updated, however I am still not getting extra posts on click of the loadmore button. I am a bit unclear as to where the posts_per_page var is declared, and where exactly it is updated.

Comment: No it's still not working for me, I have updated the code but I am not sure what I need to put on the load more function to get the next 4 posts to show. (Thanks for your continued help on this)

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I see what you are doing, it's making a lot more sense now, however, with the updated controller, on load there are no posts. When I click Load More I get the following:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Comment: @zeKoko you will need this `$scope.posts = []; //setted as blank` line at the start of controller

Comment: Fantastic that works! Thank you :)
For some reason though it doesn't stop when all articles have loaded, it just reloads all the articles again in a loop.
Do you know why that would be?

Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: @zeKoko Glad to hear that..for fixing that issue you must have check `paged` which means page count.

Comment: How do you mean? Sorry I don't fully understand.

Comment: @zeKoko sorry to say..but could you accept this answer and close this question..as it working as expected..For the page limit thing you could ask one more question so that more people will get involve on this..

Comment: Hi Yes of course. I tried to upvote earlier but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @zeKoko thats no problem..now open new question..that would give help from other people too.. Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, just realised, this isn't actually working, it is pulling in the same 4 post each time, it isn't loading more posts.

Comment: I have never used Plunkr. Sorry, this is my first time on Stack Overflow -  not sure how I can recreate what I have using plunkr as this setup is based on a whole WordPress install.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, did you get a chance to have another look? Sorry to pester you.

Comment: Hi, for anyone still interested, change 'filter[page]':  to 'filter[paged]':.